# Jetty IdleTimeout

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am migrating from jetty7.6 to jetty-9.2. I am seeing that default value of idletimeout for jetty connections is reduced 10 times.

In jetty-7.6

```
<Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
```

In jetty-9.2:

```
<Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
```

Why So ?

And because of this I am continuously getting below exception :

```
WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp607635164-14195: Commit failed
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:156)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)..........
```

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 9):

put this in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`

```
jetty.http.idleTimeout=300000
```

that will restore your previous expectations.

It was changed from a default of 5 minutes to 30 seconds as a timeout simply because that's a better choice for the majority of websites.

Comment: I saw in jetty-http.xml :  Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>   But when i tried to set java property "http.timeout" to 300000. It still shows me the same error with "30000(old value)". Why it is not set to the new value (why can't this be changed from java property) ?

Comment: That is not a java `System.setProperty`, its a `jetty-start` / `jetty-xml` startup property.  use `start.jar --list-config` capture the output, then edit your question to include this output.

Comment: FYI, this property is now `jetty.http.timeout`

Comment: @Golly I believe you mean `jetty.http.idleTimeout` since v9.3

Answer (score 0):

Using Jetty 9.4 and HTTPS, the above solution doesn't work. To fix this I found an undocumented setting that doesn't appear in the .ini files:

`jetty.ssl.idleTimeout=180000`

Add that to your Jetty settings. `start.d/<whatever>.ini` or `start.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct setting is

```html
## Connector idle timeout in milliseconds
# jetty.ssl.idleTimeout=30000
```

This can be found in ssl.mod file.